# Extract duration from Google-distance url

Tags: android, android-maps, google-distancematrix-api

I'm in the middle of developping a map app that enables user to send duration data that it takes him to get to another place, to the database (MySQL) , for this reason I tried to extract the double value of duration directely from url as it's showing in the method below :

```
  @Override
public void setDouble(String result) {
    String res[]=result.split(",");
    Double min=Double.parseDouble(res[0])/60;
    int dist=Integer.parseInt(res[1])/1000;
    Duree.setText("Duration= " + (int) (min / 60) + " hr " + (int) (min % 60) + " mins");
    Distance.setText("Distance= " + dist + " kilometers");
}
```

In this method it worked, but when I tried to do it like this :

```
url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="+latt+","+lngg+"&destinations="+lt+","+lg+"&mode=driving&language=fr-FR&avoid=tolls&key=API_KEY";
String res[]=url.split(",");
Double duration=Double.parseDouble(res[0])/60;
```

It showed me that it's not a valid double value, knowing that I need to send this value when I click a button showed on a popup window after marker click (So the problem of inner class is posed).
Can you help me know what is the right way to do it ,if that is possible !

Answer (score 1):

Don't expect your first result-field contains the duration but make your parsing a little more intelligent. Use, by example, the org.json library ([introduction on json](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-org-json/)

Following code snippet should help a little:

```
LOGGER.debug("---google duration in seconds = {}", jsonElement.opt("duration") == null ? 0 : jsonElement.getJSONObject("duration").get("value"));

transportInfo.setDuration(jsonElement.opt("duration") == null ? 0 : (Integer) jsonElement.getJSONObject("duration").get("value"));
```

And, btw, I would recommend removing your API key ASAP from your post .... Be aware this key could be used by other people.